# Exact Sequences of Modules and Rank

Tags: modules, linear-transformations, exact-sequence

Suppose that:

$0 \rightarrow M_{1} \rightarrow M \rightarrow M_{2} \rightarrow 0$

Is an exact sequence of $R$-modules (for $R$ commutative integral domain). Show that $\mathrm{rk}(M) = \mathrm{rk}(M_{1})+\mathrm{rk}(M_{2})$

---

I have shown the inequality $\mathrm{rk}(M) \geq \mathrm{rk}(M_{1})+\mathrm{rk}(M_{2})$, however for the opposite direction I'm lost. I tried to take $N$ as a linear independent subset and tried to decompose it into $N_{1}$ (the elements in $\mathrm{Ker}(g)$) and $N_{2}$ (the elements not in $\mathrm{Ker}(g)$), but I haven't got far, since $N_{1}$ gives us a linearly independent set in $M_{1}$, however $N_{2}$ can give us a linearly dependent set in $M_{2}$.

We define $\mathrm{rk}(M)$ in this case as the supremum over all cardinalities of the linearly independent subsets of $M$ (where the only finite linear combination equaling $0$ implies trivial coefficients for $r \in R$).

Would this be the proper way to show the result? I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$. If we define rank as $\operatorname{dim}_K (M \otimes_R K) $ then $0 \rightarrow M_{1} \otimes_R K \rightarrow M \otimes_R K \rightarrow M_{2} \otimes_R K \rightarrow 0$ is exact ($K$ is flat) and the equality is true because dim is an additive function on vector spaces

Comment: I see. Is there a way to do it without tensor products? I haven't seen them yet. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Truthfully I had to look up the definition of rank and the expression $\operatorname{dim}_K (M \otimes_R K)$ is all I found

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll make an edit to the question.

Comment: You can do it with rings of fractions:  for any multiplicative subset of $R$, the sequence $0\to S^{-1}M_1\to S^{-1}M_2\to S^{-1}M_3\to 0$ is exact, and specify $S=R\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

*I am aware of the fact, that passing to the quotient field by localization or tensoring gives us an easy proof, but the OP asked for something more elementary.*

First of all some notations: Denote the map $M \to M_2$ by $f$ and identify $M_1$ as the kernel of $f$, i.e. view $M_1$ as a subset of $M$.

Here is an elementary proof for the inequality

$$\operatorname{rk} M \leq \operatorname{rk} M_1 + \operatorname{rk} M_2.$$

Take $R$-linear independent subset $N \subset M$. Let $X \subset N$ be maximal with respect to the property that $f(X)$ is linear independent in $M_2$.

Now let $m \in N \setminus X$. The set $f(\{m\} \cup X)$ is linear dependent, hence we have some $r_m, \lambda_{m,x} \in R$ such that

$$0=r_mf(m) + \sum_{x \in X} \lambda_{m,x}f(x) = f\left(r_mm+\sum_{x \in X} \lambda_{m,x}x \right),$$

hence $r_mm+\sum_{x \in X} \lambda_{m,x}x \in M_1$.

Note that we have $r_m \neq 0$, since $f(X)$ is linear independent.

Let us proof that the elements $(r_mm+\sum_{x \in X} \lambda_{m,x}x)_{m \in N \setminus X}$ are linear indepedendent:

Let $\mu_m \in R$ such that

$$\sum_{m \in N \setminus X } \mu_m(r_mm+\sum_{x \in X} \lambda_{m,x}x) = 0$$

We rearrange this sum and get:

$$0=\sum_{m \in N \setminus X} \mu_mr_mm + \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{m \in N \setminus X} \mu_m\lambda_{m,x}x$$

The linear independence of $N$ yields (in particular) $\mu_mr_m=0$, hence $\mu_m=0$, since $r_m \neq 0$ and $R$ is an integral domain. This shows that the elements are indeed linear independent.

All in all we have shown:

We can split $N$ into a disjoint union $N = (N \setminus X) \cup X$, such that the elements of $N \setminus X$ are linear indepedenent in $M_1$ and the elements of $X$ are linear independent after passing to $M_2$. Thus we are done.

---

To the other inequality

$$\operatorname{rk} M \geq \operatorname{rk} M_1 + \operatorname{rk} M_2.$$

You have already shown this, so I only give a sketch:

Take a linear indepedent set $N_1 \subset M_1$ and another $N_2 \subset M_2$. View $N_1$ as set in $M$ in take arbitrary inverse images of the elements in $N_2$ to form a set $f^*(N_2)$ (which is in bijection with $N_2$). Then $N_1 \cup f^*(N_2)$ is a linear independent family in $M$, which proves the inequality. Note that this works over any commutative ring with unity, we can **allow zero-divisors** for this. (But we need the integral domain property for the other inequality as seen above)